# Duda con la interacción Maven - Heroku

Tags: maven, heroku, deployment, build

¿Cuál es la interacción entre Heroku y Maven?

Tengo entendido que Maven es la herramienta de build que ayuda al deploy y que Heroku es una PaaS que concretamente sirve para el deploy, entonces, ¿la interacción sería algo como que Maven le dice a Heroku cuán hacer el deploy o no es necesariamente de esa forma?

Comment: Te contradices, Maven -> hace deploy (bien), Heroku -> PaaS (bien), pero tu duda es: *Maven -> decir a -> Heroku -> hacer deploy* (*Maven le dice a Heroku cuán hacer el deploy*). Heroku no hace deploy, lo hace Maven. Sin embargo Heroku te provee de un [plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) para Maven, de tal manera que cuando Maven hace el deploy, usará la API de Heroku para crear el ensamblado en la plataforma. Saludos

Comment: Queda claro. Gracias!!!